# Firebase facebook sign-in not prompting facebook log-in

Tags: facebook, heroku, oauth, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, while working from my local host, everything with the facebook log-in through firebase worked fine.  when i hosted the site through heroku, the sign-in feature quits working.  The firebase function runs, but the facebook login never comes up, so I get a null user.

```
//Initiallizes firebase on the page
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//Create the provider object *look at at window*
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

//Adds profile photo album as additional scope.  We will need these for the user to pick from for the scan
provider.addScope('user_photos');
provider.addScope('user_location');


$('#signUp').click(function(){
console.log("button clicked");
//sign-in by redirect
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    console.log("attempting log in")
  if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // ...
  }
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  console.log(user);

  var userName = result.user.displayName;
  //console.log(userName);

  var userEmail = result.user.email;

  var userPhoto = result.user.photoURL;

  var userLocation = result.user.location;

  //Creates a local storage spage for the user's info for the page's duration on the user's browser
  sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({user: userName, photo: userPhoto, location: userLocation}));

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/signUp",
      data: {user: userName, email: userEmail, profilePic: userPhoto}
    })
      .done(function( data ) {
        if (data.error) {
            alert(data.error);
        }
        alert(data.msg);
        window.location = data.url;
      });

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});

// firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
//   // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
//   var token = result.credential.accessToken;
//   // The signed-in user info.
//   var user = result.user;


//   // ...
// }).catch(function(error) {
//   // Handle Errors here.
//   var errorCode = error.code;
//   var errorMessage = error.message;
//   // The email of the user's account used.
//   var email = error.email;
//   // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
//   var credential = error.credential;
//   // ...
// });
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
});

$('#signIn').click(function(){
console.log("button clicked");
//sign-in by redirect
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // ...
  }
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  console.log(user);

  var userName = result.user.displayName;
  //console.log(userName);

  var userEmail = result.user.email;

  var userPhoto = result.user.photoURL;

  var userLocation = result.user.location;

  //Creates a local storage spage for the user's info for the page's duration on the user's browser
  sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({user: userName, photo: userPhoto, location: userLocation}));

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/signIn",
      data: {user: userName, email: userEmail, profilePic: userPhoto}
    })
      .done(function( data ) {
        if (data.error) {
            alert(data.error);
        }
        alert(data.msg);
        window.location = data.url;
      });

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});

// firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
//   // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
//   var token = result.credential.accessToken;
//   // The signed-in user info.
//   var user = result.user;


//   // ...
// }).catch(function(error) {
//   // Handle Errors here.
//   var errorCode = error.code;
//   var errorMessage = error.message;
//   // The email of the user's account used.
//   var email = error.email;
//   // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
//   var credential = error.credential;
//   // ...
// });
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
});
```